# exception in vmware

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation, drag-and-drop

I am using VMWare 7.1.3 in WIndows 7,and I have built two vitual machines,one is ubuntu,and the other is xp.

However I found some exceptions when I run them:

In the virtual machine,no matter in xp or ubuntu,if I open a **terminal window**,then once I move the window by **drag the title bar**,my command which is running in the terminal will be stoped just as I enter '**ctrl+c**' manually.

Very strange,I wonder anyone meet this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ctrl  + c actually stops many commands in Linux and ms dos batches.... it was so since years in the past... Unluckily is the same command to copy stuff in Windows...

Look if it's related to this. Anyway, something should appear, some message of interruption.

Usually anyway, there are other ways to copy the text from console. In XP DOS window, click right mouse button, "Mark" and drag a sort of window to select.(that'd copy it).In linux, it depends, often just selecting it.